# Баны и муты в телеграм бот апи

Tags: python, telebot

Кто может подсказать как выдавать муты и баны в telegramm, используя бота и python. Напиример /mute @durov 2h и бот выдавал мут на 2 часа. Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Используйте `split()`, например: `args = message.text.split()` или `user, hours = message.get_args().split()`, а дальше обрабатывайте как вам нужно исходя из этих данных

Comment: Это отлично, а какая функция telebot позволяет выдать мут и бан?

Comment: Сергей, используйте [ban_chat_member](https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sync_version/index.html#telebot.TeleBot.ban_chat_member). А для мута нет метода, нужно придумать самому, как вариант использовать `delete_message`

Comment: На счет мута, я имею ввиду редактирование разрешений и запрет писать пользователю

Comment: Вот поэтому запрет писать юзеру можно сделать с помощью `delete_message`

Comment: Но если я не ошибаюсь то delete_message будет просто удалять сообщения, а мне нужно чтобы у человека вместо поля ввода было написано "Администраторы запретили вам писать до 19 февраля 22:00"

Comment: Сергей, вместо какого поля ввода? Что вы хотите, так и непонятно. Где бот, как он взаимодействует с юзером и т.д.

Comment: Покапавшись в одной из версий документации нашел метод restrict_chat_member, это то что мне нужно

Comment: `restrict` тоже как решение